# SpriteKit - Player inside of Object

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 2d, collision-detection

I am currently working at a 2D endless runner. In the game you can change the state of the character and then walk through objects. But if the player is inside of an object, he is not supposed to be able to change back to the other state, until he left the object.

Currently I am checking this state like this:

```
    if((thePlayer.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies())! != [])
    {
        for object in (thePlayer.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies())!
        {
            guard let node = object.node
            else
            {
                return
            }

            // Player IN a Block?

            if  node.frame.minX < thePlayer.frame.maxX - 1 &&
                node.frame.maxX > thePlayer.frame.minX + 1 &&
                node.frame.maxY > thePlayer.frame.minY + 1 &&
                node.frame.minY < thePlayer.frame.maxY - 1
                {
                    //Player is IN a Block
                    isInBlock = true
                }

        }
    }
```

I am not really happy with that solution, because I add new level sequences through a SKReferenceNode and the level objects within that node do not respond to that way of checking.

I assume it is because nodes inside of the SKReferenceNode use the SKReferenceNode's coordinate system, while the player uses the main one.

Anyways, I am not really sure, if this is the best solution anyways. 
What would be a better way to do it? 
Or how could I at least solve the SKReferenceNode problem?

EDIT:
I changed the structure of my code so that now I am only checking the collision, whenever the player taps the screen. 
This still leaves the problem about the coordinate system and the SKReferenceNode open. 
I took a closer look and now I am sure, that this is the problem.

How can I get the position a node inside of a SKReferenceNode has in the coordinate system of the main scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I kept my initial solution, because I am only checking whether the player is inside a block when the user changes the state of the character. This makes the code very efficient because is also only checks the nodes, which are touching the player in this moment.

I also fixed my remaining problem, which was that the nodes I added through a SKReferenceNode used another coordinate system than the player. 
Now I just take the X position of the SKReferenceNode and add it to the X position of the colliding node. Not the best solution, but it works just fine.